# How to display long string data from JSON as a list wise using react typescript

Tags: html, reactjs, regex, typescript, react-redux

How to display long string data from JSON as a list wise if Description string is too long. How do i split or format description Using react and typescript .

**I have below JSON data:**

```
"options": [
              {
                "perkType": "GIFT_CARD",
                "tierRewardId": "ff592a61-3e64-474e-a3e5-cb7c14cc73e1",               
                "perkDescription": "**Important details about the Perk:**\n*   Perks are random additional items. These are not earned, but extra items given to customers outside of the spend levels.\n*   See Terms and Conditions for exclusions and additional information.\n* [Terms & Conditions](www.xyz.net/TermsandConditions)",               
              },
              {
                "tierRewardId": "0aa6b029-3179-41dd-8726-78ca7e4bfe18",                
                "perkType": "TOOL_RENTAL",              
                "perkDescription": "**Important details about the Mik Perk:**\n*   Mik Perks are random additional items. These are not earned, but extra items given to customers outside of the spend levels.\n*   See Terms and Conditions for exclusions and additional information.\n*  [Terms & Conditions](www.xyz.net/TermsandConditions)"
              }
            ],
```

**already i filter the data :**

```
const optionGift = this.state.currentData.item.tierPerks[0].options.filter(
        (list) => list.perkType === 'GIFT_CARD');
    const optionGiftCard= optionGift.map((value)=> value );
    const OptionRental = this.state.currentData.item.tierPerks[0].options.filter(
        (list) => list.perkType === 'TOOL_RENTAL',);
    const OptionRentalTool= OptionRental.map((value)=> value );
```

**component tsx code :**

```
  <div> <ul className="YourPerkOption__modelParagraph">
              <li>{props.optionGiftCard[0].perkDescription}</li></ul></div>
```

I am trying to display a list wise data into below format
[image]

if anybody can help please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Custom Code

If I am understanding this correctly, the first line of the `perkDescription` is the title (`**Important details about the Mik Perk:**`) and the subsequent lines are bullet points.  We need to break up the `string` into multiple `string` segments and then render them to the DOM through JSX.  Let's make that into it's own reusable component.

The only prop that we need is the `string` text.

```
interface PerkDescriptionProps {
  text: string;
}
```

Our component breaks that `text` into an `array` of `lines` with the [`string.Prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.  We store the first element of the array to a variable `title` and the rest of the lines to another variable `bullets` using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#rest_syntax_parameters).  We then loop through the `bullets` array and put each one inside of a `li` element.

```
export const PerkDescription = ({ text }: PerkDescriptionProps) => {
  const lines = text.split("\n");
  const [title, ...bullets] = lines;
  return (
    <div className="perkDescription">
      <div className="perkDescriptionTitle">{title}</div>
      <ul className="perkDescriptionList">
        {bullets.map((line, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{line}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You would call it like this:

```
<PerkDescription text={optionGiftCard[0].perkDescription} />
```

But I think you should create a `Perk` component that uses this `PerkDescription`!

I am not dealing with the asterisks here so you'll still see them in the HTML output.  Are you using some some of package to parse markdown syntax?

#### Markdown Parsing

Your JSON is using a standardized [markdown syntax](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#unordered-lists) to denote the list. There are already packages out there which can handle the bulleted list as well as turning the link into an `a` element and adding the bold styling to the title.

Using [`react-markdown`](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown), all you need to do is put your text inside of a `ReactMarkdown` component.

```
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
```

```
<ReactMarkdown>{optionGiftCard[0].perkDescription}</ReactMarkdown>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RegEx to split perkDescription into an array and then map that array.